# How can i print to an alternate LPD port from Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows, lpr, printing

I have a Mac setup using LPD to a remote printer/port and it works great. I'm trying to add the same printer on a Windows server and it fails.

I've tried standard TCP/IP port specifying the IP as 9.3.3.3:1234 and also LPR Port. With Standard TCP I've also removed the port and configured as raw with the alternate port #.

I've got windows firewall set to allow anything outgoing to port 1234.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to install the LPR Port Monitor feature:

> The Line Printer Remote (LPR) Port Monitor feature allows windows to
>   print to the Line Printer Daemon (LPD) service on a UNIX print server.